# How to rewrite a bogus URL for my site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a Drupal 7 site and checking the log reveals a pretty regular stream of people or bots trying to access:

http://www.example.com/en/villa-for-sale/fantastic-villa-fabulous-views-and-very-spacious-interiors+Result:+chosen+nickname+%22qfgsodmn21%22;+success;

The bogus part is everything from the plus sign:
+Result:+chosen+nickname+%22qfgsodmn21%22;+success;

Going here returns a page not found page, but clearly takes up system resources and they're up to no good, so I want to fix it, but I can't for the life of me find the right RedirectMatch command or ReWriteRule to do so. I think part of the problem may be that %22 translates as quotes...

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Many thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just match for the `+Result` bit:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)\+Result: /$1
```

This will redirect the request to the URL without the `+Result:` bit

Comment: Is .htaccess going to see literal +'s at that point, or have they already been converted to spaces? If the latter, `^(.*)\ Result:` might work.

Comment: Many thanks - that worked - just would like to return a forbidden page rather than use up resources if at all possible. Not to worry if not!

Comment: @Michael You can't return a forbidden error using `RedirectMatch`, you can return the page, but it won't be a 403 error code. If you want to just return the page, replace `/$1` with your forbidden page.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just return a forbidden code—why use up resources serving the front page?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \+Result YourForbiddenPage.html [F]
```

Comment: Many thanks - I'd prefer this, but it didn't work for me. The RedirectMatch above did work - is there a way to get RedirectMatch to return a forbidden page? I've googled this, but haven't solved it yet.